# Skip certificate verification in Chrome headless (in WebDriver)

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, ssl-certificate, google-chrome-headless

I've setup a Selenium Grid Hub (via Docker) with one `Google Chrome` node. I'm using `Google Chrome 75.0.3770.100` and `ChromeDriver 75.0.3770.140`.

All that setup works fine, but somehow, it looks like Google Chrome cannot access the website I want to test (inside the corporate network) in question. I'm making screenshots when something fails, and those are blank.

So, I went ahead, jumped into the `Chrome` container, executed a "basic" `cURL` command...and it didn't work. Then I put the `-k` option and it did work with some issues (`SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.`):

```sh
$ curl -i -k -v https://hostname.tld/context/
*   Trying IP_FOR_HOSTNAME_TLD...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to https://hostname.tld (IP_FOR_HOSTNAME_TLD) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* (304) (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: C=US; O=XXX; OU=YYY; OU=ZZZ; OU=Devices; CN=hostname.tld
*  start date: Sep 28 13:00:31 2017 GMT
*  expire date: Sep 28 13:30:31 2020 GMT
*  issuer: ...
*  SSL certificate verify result: unable to get local issuer certificate (20), continuing anyway.
> GET /context/ HTTP/1.1
> Host: hostname.tld
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200
HTTP/1.1 200
Date: Mon, 05 Aug 2019 20:40:17 GMT
Server: Apache
...
</html>
* Connection #0 to host hostname.tld left intact
```

So basically, I know I have connectivity.

Now I'm trying to do the same with `Google Chrome`: `google-chrome --headless --disable-gpu --reduce-security-for-testing --disable-web-security --ignore-certificate-errors --dump-dom https://hostname.tld/context/` ...but it doesn't matter what switch I use to skip/bypass any TLS/SSL issue(s), it never works.

Is there any way to tell `Google Chrome` to skip any issues regarding invalid certificates, etc.? — like the `-k` option in `cURL`?

---

**UPDATE**

I'm using WebdriverIO and I'm also setting `acceptInsecureCerts: true` in the `capabilities` array:

```
capabilities: [
  {
    // acceptSslCerts: true,
    acceptInsecureCerts: true,
    browserName: "chrome",
    maxInstances: 1,
    "goog:chromeOptions": {
      args: [ // https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/
        "--disable-gpu",
        "--disable-web-security",
        "--headless",
        "--ignore-certificate-errors",
        // "--log-level=2", // INFO = 0, WARNING = 1, LOG_ERROR = 2, LOG_FATAL = 3
        // "--no-sandbox",
        "--window-size=1024x768",
      ],
    },
  },
],
```

Comment: From the discussion here https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/headless-dev/aMYV6ypuOvg . This issue in headless mode can be solved by setting https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Security#method-setIgnoreCertificateErrors to true (CDP). In latest Alpha version of selenium you can use CDP https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/devtools/security/Security.java#L46 Example Test https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/test/org/openqa/selenium/devtools/ChromeDevToolsSecurityTest.java#L53

Comment: It seems you don't have to call CDP directly . As its implemented in chromedriver now for headless https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=721739#c95 . Just try setting capability acceptInsecureCerts= True

Comment: I'm doing that already; since I'm using WebdriverIO, it goes into the `capabilities` array — take a look at the updated question. I've tried everything, I have no idea what else to do or how to better debug this.

Comment: Are you able to access the site without --headless in chrome node https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/tree/master/NodeChromeDebug try to interact using vnc to check certificate error etc

Comment: I didn't know about that trick; let me try to go that route and see what's going on with the browser UI. Thanks!

Comment: I was able to see the browser as you told me. Funny thing is, I still can't see the website, but if I get into Incognito mode, I get an error message (`NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`), but I can go into `Advanced` and `Proceed to https://hostname.tld (unsafe)`. I think I would have to install a valid certificate and make it available to `Google Chrome` in the end.